# PSCP: Upload an entire folder, Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, putty, scp, upload

I am using PSCP to upload some files from Windows to Linux. I can do it fine just uploading one file at a time. But I have some very large directories and I want to upload an entire directory at once.

I have tried:

```
pscp -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\* root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/*
```

Throws error: "pscp: remote filespec /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/*: not a directory"

and

```
pscp -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\ root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/
```

Throws error: "scp: includes: not a regular file"

and

```
pscp -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes
```

Throws error: "scp: includes: not a regular file"

Comment: Did you try adding `-r`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Two problems:  First, the * does not go on the destination side.  Second, `-r` is for copying an entire directory and subdirectories.

```
pscp -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\* root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/
```

Will copy all of the files in the local `includes\` directory to the `.../includes/` directory on the server.

```
pscp -r -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\ root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
```

Will copy the `includes\` directory itself, including all files and subdirectories, to the `.../ROOT/` directory on the server (where the contents of the local directory would merge with any existing `.../ROOT/includes/` directory.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer:

You don't need to use `-i` for this. It's for private key file authentication. Just use `-r` to copy the source files recursively.

You might want a drag and drop method since you're using Windows. You can - for example - use [WINSCP client](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to copy a directory and its contents you don't need to provide a file specification for the destination. Just use the directory name, for example.

```
pscp  -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\* root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/
```

If you want to copy the directory and everything below it then you can use `-r`:

```
pscp -r -i C:\sitedeploy\abt-keypair.ppk includes\ root@mysite.com:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/includes/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the folder itself with everything under it, you must use a command as below:

```
pscp -r -i C:\PrivateKeys\MyPrivateKey.ppk C:\FOLDER1 <username>@<server_id>:/home/<username>/
```

But notice there is no slash at the end of folder path  "C:\FOLDER";
if you use it with an ending slash like "C:\FOLDER1\" it doesn't copy the folder itself, but only copies everything under the folder.